# Négation dans une tournure interrogative

Tags: grammaire, négation, interrogative

À l'oral ou à l'écrit, on peut parfois utiliser la négation dans des tournures interrogatives pour exprimer une présupposition. Par exemple :

- *Je me demande si c'est le gars dont on parlait hier.*
- *Je me demande si ce n'est pas le gars dont on parlait hier.*

Ou bien :

- *Elle se demandait si elle avait déjà rencontré cet homme.*
- *Elle se demandait si elle n'avait pas déjà rencontré cet homme.*

J'ai l'impression qu'il y a une différence de sens : pour une tournure positive, on se demande innocemment si c'est le cas ou non ; pour une tournure négative, on vient d'avoir l'impression que c'est le cas et on cherche à vérifier.

Comment analyse-t-on cette nuance grammaticalement ? Est-ce que cette tournure porte un nom ?

Comment: En ce qui concerne simplement le nom de la tournure, on parle fréquemment, et sans suprise sur le terme, de *forme interro-négative*

Comment: … indirecte, en l'occurence, et [à tout le moins](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4403/1514). (@RomainVALERI)

Answer (score 4):

Je confirme la nuance dans le sens : avec une tournure négative, on commence par affirmer que c'est bien le cas, et ensuite, on émet un doute concernant cette affirmation.

Autrement dit, le doute exprime une faible probabilité : soit une faible probabilité que ça soit le cas (« est-ce que par hasard ça serait… »), soit une faible probabilité que ça ne soit *pas* le cas (« c'est lui, mais est-ce que par hasard je me tromperais ? »).

[Ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=51479&titre=De+vs+du+avec+une+phrase+n%E9gative), on affirme que « la forme négative […] exprime un soupçon, une hypothèse probable. »

<strike><sub>Je ne lui trouve pas de nom</sub></strike> mais Romain [suggère](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/negation-dans-une-tournure-interrogative/4403#comment7999_4402) *forme interro-négative* [qui a l'air](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-73302.php) de correspondre, avec cette nuance que tes interrogatives à toi sont indirectes. Il semble y avoir tout de même [plus](http://r-eveillez-vous.fr/linterro-negation-qui-nen-peut-plus-de-toujours-poser-les-mauvaises-questions/)¹ que ce que tu décris à cette interro-négative, tu cherches peut-être une dénomination plus spécifique.

<sub>¹ Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec l'analyse proposée.</sub>

Comment: Ceci est un commentaire, n'est-ce pas ? ;-)

Comment: Je me demande si ça n'en serait pas un !

Answer (score 3):

Intuitivement, il me semble que quand on dit **Je me demande si c'est le gars dont on parlait hier**, j'exprime l'idée que j'ai les moyens de répondre à ma question, par exemple en cherchant dans ma mémoire, en retrouvant la scène, etc ; mais quand je dis **Je me demande si ce n'est pas le gars dont on parlait hier**, j'exprime l'idée que je n'ai pas les moyens de répondre moi même, car le souvenir est trop nébuleux, ou que le phénomène est trop extraordinaire et il faudrait une autre confirmation, ou autre.

Une variante de sens du second cas est que je voudrais parler comme si ce n'était pas moi qui disait que *le gars était celui dont on parlait hier*, le **je me demande** fonctionnant comme une négation, et que l'ensemble donne une double négation, et que donc on a une affirmation puisque double négation = affirmation. (hein ? ). Personne ne disant vraiment que *c'est le gars vu hier*, la chose devient affirmée mais impossible à mettre en doute ; c'est un mécanisme de formation de tabous.

Ce second cas ressemble à *la faible probabilité que ça ne soit pas le cas* dont parle Nikana Reklawyks dans sa réponse.

Dans les deux cas le **si ce n'est pas** ne se rapporterait donc pas à l'objet dit (ici l'identité de la personne), mais à quelque chose du locuteur : soit son espace de mémoire, soit son absence feinte.

Hugh.